# Python Beginners 3 - How do I create a loop that does this?

Tags: string, loops, python-3.x, replace

I want to create a loop that goes through a string, and if the letter 'r' follows a vowel, it would remove the vowel. For example:

```
Enter word: Cracker
New word: Crackr
```

or

```
Enter word: Flirk
New word: Flrk
```

I already have a way of doing this, but it is not very neat. I just want to know how I can improve myself. The way I do it is:

```
  if "ar" in s or "er" in s or "ir" in s or "or" in s or "ur" in s:
      s = s.replace("ar","r")
      s = s.replace("er","r")
      s = s.replace("ir","r")
      s = s.replace("or","r")
      s = s.replace("ur","r")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions for this:

```
import re

s = re.sub("[aeiou]r", "r", s) # remove a vowel preceding `r`
```

Comment: He wants a loop though.

Comment: @RamchandraApte: `for vowel in "aeiou": s = s.replace(vowel + 'r', 'r')` loop would be less appropriate here (note: it might produce a different result if there are multiple vowels before `'r'`).